# Java login system using JSP and servlets

Tags: java, beginner, mysql, servlets, jsp

The system is pretty simple. Here is how the database looks:

```
 table users:
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | userid   | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | username | varchar(45) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | password | varchar(32) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | email    | varchar(75) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    table banbyip
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | ipAddr | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    table banlist
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | ipAddr | varchar(45) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    table loginattempts
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | ipaddr   | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | username | varchar(45) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | count    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Here are the jsp, they are the pages shown to the user(View):
Home:

```
index.jsp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login System</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
               <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

               <!-- jQuery library -->
               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

               <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
               <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- End Bootstrap -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.jsp"> Login </a> </li>
                <li><a href="register.jsp"> Register </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Login:
    login.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Login</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
               <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

               <!-- jQuery library -->
               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

               <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
               <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- End Bootstrap -->
    </head>
    <body>  
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="login.jsp"> Login </a> </li>
                <li><a href="register.jsp"> Register </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
         <form action="login" method="POST" role="form">
             <c:if test="${sessionScope.failed == 1}">
                 <div class="form-group">
                    <h3>Login failed</h3>
                 </div>
             </c:if>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Register:

```
register.jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Register</title>
              <!-- Bootstrap -->
               <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

               <!-- jQuery library -->
               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

               <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
               <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- End Bootstrap -->
    </head>
    <body>
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default" >
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.jsp"> Login </a> </li>
                <li class="active"><a href="register.jsp"> Register </a> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <form action="register" method="POST" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <c:if test="${sessionScope.Invalid_username == 1}">
                    <h6> Invalid username </h6><br />
                    <c:set var="Invalid_username" value="0" scope="session"  />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${sessionScope.unameAlreadyRegistered == 1}">
                    <h6> Username is already registered</h6><br />
                    <c:set var="unameAlreadyRegistered" value="0" scope="session"  />
                </c:if>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <c:if test="${sessionScope.mailAlreadyRegistered == 1}">
                    <h6> E-mail is already registered</h6><br />
                    <c:set var="mailAlreadyRegistered" value="0" scope="session"  />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${sessionScope.Invalid_email == 1}">
                    <h6> E-mail is invalid</h6><br />
                    <c:set var="Invalid_email" value="0" scope="session"  />
                </c:if>
                <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <c:if test="${sessionScope.Invalid_password == 1}">
                    <h6> Password is invalid</h6><br />
                    <c:set var="Invalid_password" value="0" scope="session"  />
                </c:if>
                <c:if test="${sessionScope.passwordsDontMatch == 1}">
                    <h6> Passwords don't match</h6><br />
                    <c:set var="passwordsDontMatch" value="0" scope="session"  />
                </c:if>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="passwordRepeat">Repeat password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="passwordRepeat" name="passwordRepeat" placeholder="Repeat password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

banned.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1251"%>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251"/>
        <title>banned</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        You are banned
    </body>
</html>
```

And here are the Java classes, which are helping the servlets to do their job.

DataBase.java

```
package loginsystem;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DataBase {

    private final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/loginsystem";
    private final String username = "root";
    private final String password = "123456";

    private Connection connection;
    private PreparedStatement statement;

    public DataBase() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, username, password);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occured: " + e.toString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("An exception occured: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public Object[] createParams(Object... args) {
        Object params[] = new Object[args.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            params[i] = args[i];
        }
        return params;
    }

    public ResultSet runSQL(String sql, Object[] params, boolean isUpdate) {
        if (!validateSQL(sql, params)) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                int j = i + 1;
                statement.setObject(j, params[i]);
            }
            if (isUpdate) {
                statement.executeUpdate();
                return null;
            } else {
                return statement.executeQuery();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public int getUserId(String username) {
        String sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ?;";
        int id;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            id = rs.getInt("user_id");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
            id = -1;
        }
        return id;
    }

    private boolean validateSQL(String sql, Object[] params) {
        int objectsCount = params.length;
        int questionMarks = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < sql.length(); i++) {
            if (sql.charAt(i) == '?') {
                questionMarks++;
            }
        }
        return objectsCount == questionMarks;
    }

}
```

Logger.java

```
package loginsystem;


import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Logger {

    private final String checkIfRecordExists = "SELECT ipaddr FROM loginattempts WHERE ipaddr = ?;";
    private final String clearRecord = "UPDATE loginattempts SET count = 0 WHERE ipaddr = ?;";
    private final String incrementRecord = "UPDATE loginattempts SET count = count + 1 WHERE ipaddr = ?";
    private final String addRecord = "INSERT INTO loginattempts(ipaddr, username, count) VALUES(?, ?, 0)";
    private final String getCountByUserName = "SELECT count FROM loginattempts WHERE  username = ?";
    private final String getCountByIp = "SELECT count FROM loginattempts WHERE ipaddr = ?";
    private final String getCount = "SELECT count FROM loginattempts WHERE ipaddr = ? AND username = ?";
    private final DataBase db = new DataBase();
    public Logger() {

    }

    public boolean checkIfRecordExists(String IP) {
        boolean retVal = false;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            rs = db.runSQL(checkIfRecordExists, db.createParams(IP), false);
            retVal = rs.isBeforeFirst();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public void clearRecord(String IP) {
        if (!checkIfRecordExists(IP)) {
            return;
        }
        db.runSQL(clearRecord, db.createParams(IP), true);
    }

    public void incrementRecord(String IP, String username) {
        if (!checkIfRecordExists(IP)) {
            addRecord(IP, username);
        } else {
            db.runSQL(incrementRecord, db.createParams(IP), true);
        }
    }

    public int getCountByUserName(String username) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            ResultSet rs = db.runSQL(getCountByUserName, db.createParams(username), false);
            while (rs.next()) {
                count += rs.getInt("count");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        return count;
    }

    public int getCountByIp(String IP) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            ResultSet rs = db.runSQL(getCountByIp, db.createParams(IP), false);
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
                count += rs.getInt("count");
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        return count;
    }

    public int getCount(String IP, String username) {
        int count = 0;
        try {
            ResultSet rs = db.runSQL(getCount, db.createParams(IP, username), false);
            rs.beforeFirst();
            while (rs.next()) {
                count += rs.getInt("count");
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

        return count;
    }

    private void addRecord(String IP, String username) {
        db.runSQL(addRecord, db.createParams(IP, username), true);
    }
}
```

HashingMethod.java

```
package loginsystem;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class HashingMethod 
{
   private MessageDigest md5;

   public HashingMethod(){
       try{
           md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
       }
       catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
           System.out.println(e.toString());
       }
   }

   public String hashPassword(String password){
       md5.update(password.getBytes());
       byte[] digest = md5.digest();
       StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
       for (byte b : digest) {
            strBuff.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
       }
       return strBuff.toString();
    }
}
```

BAN.java

```
package loginsystem;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class BAN {
    private String addBanUser = "INSERT INTO banlist VALUES(?)";
    private String removeBanUser = "DELETE FROM banlist WHERE userId = ?";
    private String isBannedUser = "SELECT * FROM banlist WHERE userId = ?";
    private String addBanIP = "INSERT INTO banbyip VALUES(?)";
    private String removeBanIP = "DELETE FROM banbyip WHERE ipAddr = ?";
    private String isBannedIP = "SELECT * FROM banbyip WHERE iAddr = ?";
    private DataBase db = new DataBase();
    public BAN(){

    }
    public void addBan(String param, boolean isIP){
        if(isIP)
            db.runSQL(addBanIP, db.createParams(db.getUserId(param)), false);
        else
            db.runSQL(addBanUser, db.createParams(db.getUserId(param)), false);
    }
    public void removeBan(String param, boolean isIP){
        if(isIP)
            db.runSQL(removeBanIP, db.createParams(db.getUserId(param)), false);
        else
            db.runSQL(removeBanUser, db.createParams(db.getUserId(param)), false);
    }
    public boolean isBanned(String param, boolean isIP){
     try{
        ResultSet rs;
        if(isIP)
            rs = db.runSQL(isBannedIP, db.createParams(db.getUserId(param)), true);
        else
             rs = db.runSQL(isBannedUser, db.createParams(db.getUserId(param)), true);
        return rs.isBeforeFirst();
     }catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println(e.toString());
         return false;
     }
    }
}
```

And finally here are the servlets:

Login.java

```
package loginsystem;

import java.io.IOError;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;

@WebServlet(name = "Login", urlPatterns = { "/login" })
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private final int MAX_LEN_USERNAME = 30;
    private final int MAX_LEN_PASSWORD = 32;
    private final String validateLogin = "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    private Logger logger;
    private BAN ban;
    private DataBase db;
    private HashingMethod hasher;
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=windows-1251";

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        db = new DataBase();
        ban = new BAN();
        logger = new Logger();
        hasher = new HashingMethod();
    }
    private void failedAttempt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String IP = request.getRemoteAddr();
        logger.incrementRecord(IP,username);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("failed", 1);
        if(logger.getCountByUserName(username) > 10)
            ban.addBan(username, false);
        if(logger.getCountByIp(IP) > 10)
            ban.addBan(IP,true);
        response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
    }
    private boolean validateData(String username, String password){
        if(username.equals("") || password.equals(""))
            return false;
        if(username.length() > MAX_LEN_USERNAME || password.length() > MAX_LEN_PASSWORD)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    private boolean validateLogin(String username, String password){
        ResultSet rs;
        String passwordFromDb = "";
        try{
            rs = db.runSQL(validateLogin, db.createParams(username), false);
            rs.next();
            passwordFromDb = rs.getString("password");
        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
       return passwordFromDb.equals(hasher.hashPassword(password));
    }
    private void succesullAttempt(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        response.sendRedirect("http://9gag.com");
    }
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        if(validateData(username, password)){
            if(ban.isBanned(username, false) || ban.isBanned(request.getRemoteAddr(), true))
                response.sendRedirect("banned.jsp");
            if(validateLogin(username, password)){
                succesullAttempt(request, response);
            }
            else{
                failedAttempt(request, response);
            }
        }
        else
            failedAttempt(request, response);
    }
}
```

Register.java

```
package loginsystem;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet(name = "Register", urlPatterns = { "register" })
public class Register extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=windows-1251";
    private final String checkIfUserExists = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = ?";
    private final String checkIfEmailExists = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE email = ?";
    private final String inserUser = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email) VALUES(?, ? ,?)";
    private DataBase db = new DataBase();
    private HashingMethod hasher = new HashingMethod();

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }

    private boolean validateEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN =
            "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@" + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";
        Pattern pattern;
        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher;
        matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return !matcher.matches();
    }

    private boolean checkIfUserExists(String username) {
        ResultSet rs;
        rs = db.runSQL(checkIfUserExists, db.createParams(username), false);
        try {
            return rs.isBeforeFirst();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean checkIfEmailExists(String email) {
        ResultSet rs = db.runSQL(checkIfEmailExists, db.createParams(email), false);
        try {
            return rs.isBeforeFirst();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            return true;
        }
    }

    private boolean validateInput(String username, String password, String repeatPassword, String email,
                                  HttpSession session) {
        // username
        if (username.equals("") || username.length() > 42) {
            session.setAttribute("Invalid_username", 1);
            return false;
        }
        if (checkIfUserExists(username)) {
            session.setAttribute("unameAlreadyRegistered", 1);
            return false;
        }
        // password
        if (password.equals("")) {
            session.setAttribute("Invalid_password", 1);
            return false;
        }
        if (!password.equals(repeatPassword)) {
            session.setAttribute("passwordsDontMatch", 1);
            return false;
        }
        // email
        if (email.equals("") || validateEmail(email)) {
            session.setAttribute("Invalid_email", 1);
            return false;
        }
        if (checkIfEmailExists(email)) {
            session.setAttribute("mailAlreadyRegistered", 1);
            return false;
        }
        //else
        return true;
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String username = (request.getParameter("username") != null) ? request.getParameter("username") : "";
        String password = (request.getParameter("password") != null) ? request.getParameter("password") : "";
        String passwordRepeat =
            (request.getParameter("passwordRepeat") != null) ? request.getParameter("passwordRepeat") : "";
        String email = (request.getParameter("email") != null) ? request.getParameter("email") : "";
        if (validateInput(username, password, passwordRepeat, email, request.getSession())) {
            String hashedPassword = hasher.hashPassword(password);
            db.runSQL(inserUser, db.createParams(username, hashedPassword, email), true);
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
        } else {
            response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");
        }
    }
}
```

The system is far from well written, hopefully with your help I can make it better.

Answer (score 3):

Some general stuff:

Your database code is scattered around a bit. You shouldn't be passing back `ResultSets`. You should execute the query, read the data into a Data Object and return the object (or a list of objects).

You should also use [`try`-`catch`-`finally`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114905/close-connection-and-statement-finally)  OR [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to make sure database connections are cleaned up properly.

You shouldn't store the errors in a session. Use a `List<String>` or `String[]` to hold error messages and then pass them from the Servlet to the View.

Keep your `Database` code contained. All your SQL statements in one class. All database operations in one class.  You could have a separate class for each table you are interacting with that all use the utilities of the `Database` class.

You could also move you logic to 'Service Classes' and call that from the Servlet.

```
LoginService ls = new LoginService();

ls.validate(username, password, repeatPassword, email);
```

The `validate` method could return a list of errors (empty list means no errors).